How to show $8\cdot S^2\times S^2$ is homeomorphic to $M\# N$ with unsmoothable M, N?
Here $n\cdot M$ means connected sum of $n$ copies of $M$.
If I write out intersection form of $8\cdot S^2\times S^2$, it is a 16 by 16 block matrix with each block being
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
1& 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
I must manipulate this matrix to a congruent 2-block matrix such that both blocks have nonzero signature. How do I do this?

Answer: Take the form $E_8\# -E_8$.
